# How to fix more than one columns returned error in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I was trying to write a code to fetch records from a table and group by some columns but the subquery returns "more than one" error.

When I write the codes independently, I get a great awesome result but combining them is a problem.

```
select 
    year as Season,
    cal_scheme as Scheme,
    (case when cal_scheme='Mt.Elgon' then '1000'
    when cal_scheme='West Nile' then '2000'
    when cal_scheme='Rwenzori' then '1500' else '' end) as Target,
    min(today::date) as startdatetime,
    max(today::date)-min(today::date) as No_of_days,
    (select count(id) as id from
        kcl_internal_edit where new_farmer='' or new_farmer is null
        group by year, cal_scheme)as growers
from kcl_internal_edit
    group by year, cal_scheme
```

The expected result is to be as follows:

```
Season Scheme    Target Startdatetime No_of_days  growers
2019   Mt.Elgon  1000   28-10-2019    5            5
2019   West Nile 2000   29-05-2019    10           1
2018   Mt.Elgon  1500   29-08-2018    207          3
```

Comment: I am just a newbie in DB but I chose to start with postgresql. A help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the **exact** error message you get. I assume it's "more than one **row** returned", not "more than one _column_"?

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like this:

```
select 
    year as Season,
    cal_scheme as Scheme,
    (case when cal_scheme='Mt.Elgon' then '1000'
    when cal_scheme='West Nile' then '2000'
    when cal_scheme='Rwenzori' then '1500' else '' end) as Target,
    min(today::date) as startdatetime,
    max(today::date)-min(today::date) as No_of_days,
    count(id) FILTER (WHERE new_farmer='' or new_farmer is null) as growers
from kcl_internal_edit
    group by year, cal_scheme;
```

There is no need for a subselect!